# Unable to get value from bashrc when Echoing

Tags: php, bash, git, shell, echo

Good Day Everyone,

I am currently having some difficulty setting my environment variables, I am currently using a mac as well.So, I am not a PHP user so I do not know much about the language. However, I have a few variables that I stored in my bashrc file.

I would like to retrieve them, and use it as part of my current project workflow (GIT Token).

I have a few variables stored, but it will not return any value... I am really not sure what is wrong. Please do assist me..

```
nano ~/.bashrc

export GITHUB_TOKEN= ghp_123456
export testVal = Testing
```

However when I call nothing happens

```
echo $testval
```

And when downloading a private repo it shows this error..

```
curl -sSfL -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN?not set}" -H 'Accept: application/rnd.github.v2.raw' "https://eg.git" | sh -s --

bash: GITHUB_TOKEN: not set
```

Comment: Please provide the exact steps you took to achieve these results and what results you excepted. Exclude anything that is not necessary to demonstrate this. In short, provide a [mcve].. Also, rewiew the tags you picked, they can be improved a lot. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: When I run your code, I get the error message _bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier_. I wonder why you didn't get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the equals sign, like this:

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_123456
export testVal=Testing
```

When writing `var = value` you're asking the shell to open program `var` with `=` and `value` as arguments.

Comment: Hello :) thank you for your reply, I tried that and it still didn’t work..

Comment: Have you tried reloading .bashrc? `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yeap I didn't reload :) thanks a bunch~